# Load all pages on startup in PDF.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

Hi Have problem with **PDF.js** library
I need open PDF and **render all pages** in document. 
Dont want to wait until user scrools over it.

I am using customized PDF.js [default viever](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) to do some suff, with document. 
but i need rendered all pages for this changes to work properly.

I tried in [viever.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.js)  change DEFAULT_PREFERENCES.disableRange set to true, but it doesn't work.

Have you **any** idea to solve my problem?